# Add form data to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS DynamoDB, I would like add form data which randomly entered by a user to DynamoDB without using JSON format.

Here is my sample code which is used to add data from a json file,

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var fs = require('fs');
AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
});
allMovies.forEach(function(movie) {
    var params = {
        TableName: "Movies1",
        Item: {enter code here
            "year":  movie.year,
            "title": movie.title,
            "info":  movie.info
        }
    };
    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to add movie", movie.title, ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       } else {
           console.log("PutItem succeeded:", movie.title);
       }
    });
});
```

But I want add data which is from a form. Any kind of help will be more useful.

Comment: You're going to have to supply it as JSON, just turn your form into JSON with JSON.stringify

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but without using json format can't we do it directly using variables.

Comment: No, the API for dynamoDB takes JSON, you can do Item: {movie.thing : movie.other}, but end of the day you have to supply it to dynamodb as JSON.